# Gson boolean conversion always false

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using Gson as a converter to parse my response through Retrofit, but I'm always getting false even with a positive response.

It's something like this

Response:

```
{"groups":{"success":true}}
```

GroupsResponseClass

```
public class GroupsResponse {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private boolean mSuccess;

    GroupsResponse() {}

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return mSuccess;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        mSuccess = success;
    }
}
```

I stop using GsonConverter and still get a object with a success false value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your groups object is technically nested inside another object, might need to flatten your json. If not able, this should work:

GroupsResponse.java

```
public class GroupsResponse {

    @SerializedName("groups")
    private Groups mGroups;

    GroupsResponse() {}

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return mGroups.isSuccess();
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        mGroups.setSuccess(success);
    }
}
```

Groups.java

```
public class Groups {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private boolean mSuccess;

    Groups() {}

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return mSuccess;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        mSuccess = success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the setter and getter methods important for the parsing? I have the same problem but it doesn't seem to work with the serialization annotation. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37718798/1565635