# GSON not parsing booleans (always false)

Tags: java, json, boolean, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit in order to get a JSON document. Problem is, all booleans are always false.

The response looks like this:

```
{
   "gender":[0,1],
   "age":[20,30],
   "likesLeaveHome":false,
   "likesSport":false,
   "likesCulture":false,
   "likesTraveling":false
   ...
}
```

I am calling the retrofit method with

```
onResponse(Call<SearchProfile> call, Response<SearchProfile> response)
```

And the class of SearchProfile which the response should be parsed to looks like that:

```
public class SearchProfile {

    public ArrayList<Integer> gender = new ArrayList<>(); // works fine
    public ArrayList<Integer> age    = new ArrayList<>(); // works fine

    ...

    public Boolean likesLeaveHome = true;    // always false

    @SerializedName("likesSport")
    public boolean likesSport     = true;    // always false

    @SerializedName("likesCulture")
    public Boolean likesCulture;             // always false

    @SerializedName("likesTraveling")
    public Boolean mLikesTraveling;          // always false

    public boolean isLikesTraveling() {
        return mLikesTraveling;
    }

    public void setLikesTraveling(boolean likesTraveling) {
        mLikesTraveling = likesTraveling;
    }

}
```

As you can see, it is a simple pojo class. Lists like "gender" and "age" work perfectly fine. Still, the booleans can't be set. (This is especially strange since sending this object via Retrofit sends exactly this document so GSON surely knows booleans).

As shown in the snipped, I also tried other methods like giving the **Boolean** wrapper class as type instead of boolean. 
I also used a **@SerializeName** annotation or getter and setts methods etc.
Still all booleans are always false. Even if I declare them default as true (so GSON always seems to overwrite this value with false).

Hope someone has a good idea!

Comment: What version are you using? I have tried with "2.6.2", it works fine.
"<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.6.2</version>"

Comment: Well, I'm using the internal one from the retrofit framework but as far as I know this is 2.6.2.

Comment: I am still waiting for solution @TobiasReich

Comment: Well, I haven't worked on this problem for a while but so far it seems to work right now. I'm not sure if they changed something in the API. I'm using retrofit 2.1.0 now. Maybe thats the solution. If I find some time, I'll give an answer.

Comment: Having the same issue :/

Comment: share your complete code, how are you populating age and gender ?

Comment: Uh, seriously I am not sure I still have the code anymore since I currently work in a different position. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The JSON you are parsing in your example has all the values as `false`.  When parsing, GSON will use reflection to overwrite field values for a class, meaning that whatever value is parsed from JSON will be the value of the field, regardless of how it is initialized in the class.

Here is a sample response that will cause the fields to be set to true.  Again, it's just up to whatever JSON you are parsing.

```
{
   "gender":[0,1],
   "age":[20,30],
   "likesLeaveHome":true,
   "likesSport":true,
   "likesCulture":true,
   "likesTraveling":true
   ...
}
```